# ELK - micro service and network latency monitoring

Tags: elastic-stack

Does ELK stack provide micro service and network latency monitoring in kibana?

[Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) provides details bout service request and service response duration.

In behind ELS stack should trace span events:

cs - Client Sent

sr - Server Received

ss - Server Sent

cr - Client Received

Answer (score 1):

We implemented this on our microservices platform

- incoming requests get an id
- this id persists through all calls
- data is logged from each microservice with the id attached
- by knowing which services call which the latency can be observed by looking at the requests filtered by id

A lot of the logging is done by pushing requests onto a RabbitMQ queue and then getting logstash to consume that.

Other data is obtained via filebeat transmitting the logs to logstash

Both the logs and the RabbitMQ data has the id attached so can be correlated

An alternative approach would be to build instrumentation into each microservice that specifically monitored latency and then record that directly into logstash

You might like to read https://medium.com/devopslinks/how-to-monitor-the-sre-golden-signals-1391cadc7524 for a general guide to essential monitoring that is applicable to microservices

Comment: Ok. I will look for this solution approach. But, still can I find request latency with ELK  by just streaming logs to logstash. Same as, if we stream logs to Zipkin with tracing details it will provide service request processing timings.